# Setup Cassandra Cluster AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cluster-computing

I want to setup a Cassandra 2.* Cluster composed of 3 (multiple nodes) nodes in AWS.

What are the **official** steps for doing this? base image to use, ports to open, config files, etc.

PS: Pretty much everything I found points me to DataStax site but I don't think it is free if later we decide to setup this in production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found these links which were enough to get it working.

- Install Cassandra on a Single Node Amazon Linux
  http://www.jonathanhui.com/install-cassandra-single-node-amazon-linux
- Install Cassandra on a Amazon Linux Cluste
  http://www.jonathanhui.com/install-cassandra-amazon-linux-cluster

Run into a few issues but nothing really major

- Cassandra: How to fix, ‘Fatal exception during initialization org.apache.cassandra.config. ConfigurationException: Saved cluster name Test Cluster != configured name…’?
- JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
- Can't connect to cassandra - NoHostAvailableException